# Django and aiohttp together under the same project

Tags: python, django, aiohttp

Under my Django project I have created a directory for an aiohttp service.

1) How is the best way to structure it?

This is my current structure:

```
myproject/
  myservice/
    __init__.py
    service.py
    utils.py

  myproject/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    uwsgi.py

  manage.py
```

2) If my service needs to import some settings from myproject.settings, how can I do it? Should I move service.py under the root?

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `server.py` script, which uses aiohttp should be next to your `manage.py` file.

You should probraly also add:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
from django import setup
setup()
```